# What does it mean for two numbers to be $\epsilon-$close?

Tags: real-analysis

I found  on my textbook

> [...] so those two numbers are $\epsilon-$close. QED.

What does it mean for two numbers to be $\epsilon-$close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Definition:** Let $\epsilon>0$ be a real number. We say that two numbers $x,y$ are $\epsilon$-close if and only if we have $|x-y|\leqslant\epsilon$.

That two numbers are $\epsilon$-close can be also interpreted as that the distance between those two numbers is less than or equal to $\epsilon$.

I hope this helps. 
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Answer (score 2):

Your textbook probably writes "$a$ an $b$ are $\epsilon$-close" to mean $|a-b|<\epsilon$.